# Новый поток в сервисе

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-service

Есть сервис такого типа, который запускается каждый раз при открытии приложения:

```
public class SomeService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    // Что-то происходит
                }
            }
        }).start();


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что если сначала запустить приложение,потом свернуть/закрыть (сервис продолжает работать) и затем заново открыть, сервис запустится, но будет уже два запущенных потока их `onStartCommand`.

Как можно добиться того, что бы этот поток всегда был только водной экземпляре?

Comment: Вынести поток в отдельную переменную класса-сервиса и в `onStartCommand` проверять на `null` и если не `null` не создавать новый?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а если поток будет аварийно прерван, он станет `null`?

Comment: Не знаю, не пробовал. Думаю нет. Думаю, можно проверять ещё и методами типа `isinterrupted()` что с потоком всё ОК. Если нет - создавать и стартовать заново

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, А `! isAlive` == `isInterrupted`?

Comment: @Flippy,  не знаю, никогда потоки не юзал) Надо доку читать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, доку? Нееее, лучше сразу на хабр или в enSO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class SomeService extends Service {

Thread t;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(t == null || !t.isAlive()){
    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                // Что-то происходит
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
}
```

Словами @ЮрийСПб

Comment: Если поток будет `null` то вызов `isAlive` не вызовет `NPE` так как я использую `||` а не `|`

Comment: Вы `t` присваиваете результат вызова `start()`, которая `void`

Comment: @Evgeniy, да, поправил, без IDE туго однако :D

Comment: Немного поправил: инициализация `t` в `onCreate`, а в `onStartCommand` только проверка `isAlive`. Имхо так правильней, что ли :)

Comment: Да, вы правы, так лучше :)